# Issues with BFS implementation using queues in Python resulting in attribute errors

Tags: python, data-structures, attributeerror, breadth-first-search

i am trying to implement a BFS that queues and dequeues graph nodes to lists. The implemtation is below:

```
def BFS(self):
    t = SNQ.DSAQueue()
    q = SNQ.DSAQueue()

    # Set all vertices as unvisited
    for node in iter(self.vertices):
        if node is not None:
            node.set_visited(False)

    v = self.vertices.head.getValue()  # Get the head node's value directly
    v.set_visited(False)
    print(type(v))
    print('Start:', v.get_name())
    print(type(v))
    q.enqueue(v)  # Enqueue the starting node into the queue

    while not q.is_empty():
        v = q.dequeue()
        adj_list = v.get_adjacent()
        if adj_list is not None:
            for value in adj_list:
                w = self.get_vertex(value)
                if not w.get_visited():
                    w.set_visited(True)
                    t.enqueue(w)
                    q.enqueue(w)

    print(type(t))
    while not t.is_empty():
        c = t.dequeue()
        print(type(c))
```

using:

```
graph = Graph()
graph.BFS()
```

this results in the error:

```
adj_list = v.get_adjacent()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_adjacent'
```

I suspect that the objects are not actually being queued on to the linked list properly.

for reference:

```
def get_adjacent(self):
    values = np.empty(self.count, dtype=object)
    count = 0
    for edge in self.link:
        values[count] = edge.get_to()  # Add "to" vertex
        count += 1
    return values
```

This has confused me and any help is welcome.

Thank you dearly!

Comment: What is `SNQ.DSAQueue`?

Comment: SNQ = Stack and Queue. Just an imported file that contains a Queue. If youd like i can upload this

Comment: It seems to me that this queue implementation has a bug. Why didn't you just use an implementation from the standard library like `deque`?

Comment: This tasks specifies for the learner not to use standard library queues and similar. I will try to debug the queue, thanks, and all other help is appriciated.

Comment: Please make sure the problem is reproducible. That is not possible without the definitions  of the queue and `self`. When you add that code, make sure to only add *relevant* code. It should be the minimal code needed to reproduce the problem.